# Inserting a JSON Object into a database

Tags: json, delphi, datasnap

I am building a DataSnap server in Delphi XE2, and I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to insert the JSON Object that the client sends me into a Database.

Here's the format of the object I'm receiving:

```
{"PK":0,"FIELD1":"EXAMPLE","FIELD2":5, "DATE":""}
```

The solution I found was the following code

```
with qryDBMethods do
  begin
    SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Table';
    Open;
    Append;
    FieldByName('PK')    .AsInteger := StrToInt(newId.ToString)
    FieldByName('FIELD1').AsString  := Object.Get('FIELD1').JsonValue.Value;
    FieldByName('FIELD2').AsInteger := StrToInt(Object.Get('FIELD2').JsonValue.Value); 
    FieldByName('DATE')  .AsDateTime:= Now;    
    Post;
```

After that, I would have my query component made into a JSON Object and returned to my client, but problem is, this is going to be a big application with dense tables and so doing a "SELECT * " every time I want to insert something isn't ideal. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a INSERT sentence instead.

```
with qryDBMethods do
  begin
    SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Table (PK, FIELD1, FIELD2) VALUES (:PK, :FIELD1, :FIELD2)';
    ParamByName('PK')    .Value:= StrToInt(newId.ToString)
    ParamByName('FIELD1').Value := Object.Get('FIELD1').JsonValue.Value;
    ParamByName('FIELD2').Value:= StrToInt(Object.Get('FIELD2').JsonValue.Value);    
    ExecSQL();
```

Answer (score 2):

If what the problem is the amount of data when you open a `Select * From Table`, why not do something like `Select * From Table Where 1 <> 1`?

This way you would be able to insert while not loading any result.

Other option would to make an Insert script instead.

Comment: +1 this would be better from what I can see in his approach, but slow in select because it will itrate over all records